# c++ boost websocket use event

Tags: c++, boost, websocket

I use websocket client from this example: 
[boost websocket client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp)

and it's connect fine. But how I can add some event and cout result? like in socket.io:

```
socket.on('SomeEvent', function (EventMsg)) {
        console.log(EventMsg); }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? It's difficult to help you with so little information.

Comment: i try to make some like this:  <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io.connect('https://test.com');
        socket.on('test', function (TestMsg) {
            console.log(TestMsg);
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(TestMsg)
        })
    </script> on c++